# how to create pdf files of any size in ci

Tags: php, pdf, dynamic, codeigniter-2

I use `dompdf` to create pdf files from database query in `ci`.
If I limit the rows to about 500 records then it works fine.

The problem is I have more than 5000 records and it gives me time out.

My controller method is as below:

```
public function loadPDFReports() {
    ini_set ( 'memory_limit', '1024M' );
    $data ['reports'] = $this->Red_model->loadPDFReports ();
    $size = sizeof ( $data ['reports'] );
    $all = array_chunk ( $data ['reports'], 400 );
    foreach ( $all as $chunk ) {
        $data1 ['reports'] = $chunk;
        $data1 ['page_num'] = $PAGE_NUM;
        echo "hussain: <pre>";
        print_r ( $chunk );
        $view = $this->load->view ( 'reports/pdf', $data1, TRUE );
        pdf_create ( $view, 'filename' );
    }
    $view = $this->load->view ( 'reports/pdf', $data, TRUE );
    pdf_create ( $view, 'filename' );

} // loadPDFReports()
```

As you see in the code commented, i tried to split the data into separate 400 rows each,but it works only for the first loop.

It is to mentioned that I have already loaded the `dompdf` helper in `autoload.php`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use : Increase your server **max_execution_time**